# Kafka , Java - what does this "_" represent in integer literal

Tags: java, apache-kafka

I come across the following syntax to represent an integer and it looks new to me. What does it signify

> props.put(ProducerConfig.BATCH_SIZE_CONFIG,  16_384 * 4);

How does 16384 is different from 16_384 ?

Comment: It's not, the underscore is allowed in Java numeric literals to increase readability.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's the same. You can use "_" on an integer to make it be more readable.

16_384 is more readable than 16384

16_384_000 is more readable than 16384000

Answer (score 2):

In Java SE 7 and later, any number of underscore characters (_) can appear anywhere between digits in a numerical literal. This feature enables you, for example, to separate groups of digits in numeric literals, which can improve the readability of your code.

long creditCardNumber = 1234_5678_9012_3456L;
long socialSecurityNumber = 999_99_9999L;

Comment: Both are bad examples because they are not actually numbers, you cannot add, subtract, multiply or order credit card numbers from big to small, makes no sense. Both should be Strings instead.